aspectlib: make an aspect from an instance method
I’m using Python’s aspectlib. If I try to declare an instance method as an aspect like so
from aspectlib import Aspect

class ClassAspect:
   @Aspect
   def instance_method{self, *args, **kwargs):

with this corresponding cut-point:
import ClassAspect

@ClassAspect.instance_method:
def cross_point():

, I get an error about self:
TypeError: ClassAspect.instance_method() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

How can I use an instance method as advice in aspectlib?

An instance method needs an instance. What instance should be used here? Where would that instance come from?

@user2357112, are you saying that instead of @ClassAspect.instance_method, I should do

@class_aspect_instance.instance_method```
?

Likely, but you're the only one with enough information on your use case to tell for sure.
